# No such operator torchvision::nms

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

When I try to run yoloV3 detect,it happend the error

```
op = torch._C._jit_get_operation(qualified_op_name)

RuntimeError: No such operator torchvision::nms
```

Though this code is the source code of torchvision ,I try sevaral time to correct the code by the tips  with failure.

Answer (score 2):

Install Python 3.7 instead of 3.8
Steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Megvii-BaseDetection/YOLOX
cd YOLOX
pip install requirements.txt
pip install setup.py
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I met lot of hurdles to install torch and torchvison ,I'm not reluctant to reinstall the enviroment.Running 'conda list' the version of torch and torchvison ,I found they are not incompitable,the versions of two packages installed are:

```
 torchvision-0.5.0+cu92-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
 torch-1.4.0+cpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I change the version of torchvison to

```
 torchvision-0.5.0+cpu-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I have dealt with my proplem until now.
note： the enviroment of my os and python are fellowing：

```
  Windows_X64
  python3.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. Upgrading python to 3.8 and Installing fresh `torch` and `torchvision` libraries worked for me.

```
virtualenv -p python3.8 torch17
source torch17/bin/activate
pip install cython matplotlib tqdm scipy ipython ninja yacs opencv-python ffmpeg opencv-contrib-python Pillow scikit-image scikit-learn lmfit imutils pyyaml jupyterlab==3
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I tried the solutions discussed in some [pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-no-such-operator-torchvision-nms/73489) and [github](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1916) but that did not help.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me, even without upgrading python

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem on `Ubuntu 20.04` using `python 3.7`， `pytoch1.7.1` & `cuda11.1`.

Please pay attention to install `torchvision==0.8.2+cu110` rather than `torchvision==0.8.2`. Just change the corresponding version according to your system.